# Transformar imagem em Base 64

Tags: javascript, android, json, apache-cordova

Estou transformando uma imagem que envio pela camera em base64 porem a imagem fica toda preta, não sei o que esta errado, segue abaixo o meu código

```
app.encodeImageUri(mediaFiles[i].fullPath); //Aqui envio o caminho da minha imagem da seguinte maneira 'file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/140014212.jpg'

encodeImageUri: function (imageUri)
{
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
       c.width=this.width;
       c.height=this.height;
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
    };
    img.src=imageUri;
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    alert(dataURL);

    var tb1 = '<img src=' + dataURL + '>';
    document.getElementById("imgBase64").innerHTML = tb1;

    return dataURL;
},
```

Comment: Vinicius da uma olhada nesse post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Comment: Existe algo que não está funcionando? O retorno não está dentro do esperado? Qual a dúvida?

Comment: @ErlonCharles arrumei o meu comentario, veja se agora está mais clato

Comment: veja esse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que fazendo isso, resolva o problema da imagem preta:

```
dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, "");
var tb1 = '<img src=' + dataURL + '>';
document.getElementById("imgBase64").innerHTML = tb1;
```

Mas se não rolar, aqui tem um exemplo funcional:
**http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/yvq5y/**

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver com o seguinte código:

```
convertImgToBase64URL: function (url, nome,callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
},
```

A chamada da função ficou assim:

```
app.convertImgToBase64URL(anexo[aux], ext, function(base64Img){
           /* Aqui Voce coloca a ação que deseja */
        });
```

Comment: Porem gostaria de saber se seria possível adaptar o código para enviar vídeos e áudios?