# Transformar áudio e vídeo em Base64

Tags: jquery, android, apache-cordova, mobile, jquery-mobile

Gostaria de saber se seria possível transformar vídeos e áudios em Base64, já postei uma pergunta relacionada a transformar imagem em Base64 e vocês me ajudaram, porem agora eu preciso fazer o mesmo para áudio e vídeo, eu havia pensado que seria o mesmo processo da imagem mas não esta dando certo.

Este é o link da minha pergunta anterior e a solução que encontrei também postei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81925/transformar-imagem-em-base-64/81937#81937)

A aplicação que estou desenvolvendo é mobile, preciso converter para enviar ao servidor e depois o servidor desconverter e trabalhar com o arquivo.

Este é o código do meu server side que recebe como parâmetro o arquivo em Base64 e o nome para converter e salvar em um diretório:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        System.IO.Stream body = context.Request.InputStream;
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = context.Request.ContentEncoding;
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, encoding);

        //obtem postDATA
        string postData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        NameValueCollection param = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(postData);


        //params
        // filename = nome do arquivo
        // d = conteudo binario codificado em base64
        // UserId = id do usuario
        // Date = data no formato json

        //salva arquivo

        if (param["filename"] != null && param["d"] != null)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Uploads");
            string strSaveLocation = ("C:\\Uploads") + "\\" + param["filename"];
            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(strSaveLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs1);

            try
            {
                //tenta converter vindo em base64
                byte[] decbuff = Convert.FromBase64String(param["d"]);
                bw.Write(decbuff);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //failover - salva sem conversao
                bw.Write(param["d"]);
            }

            bw.Close();
            fs1.Close();

            //responde OK
            context.Response.Write("{\"StatusRetorno\":0,\"MensagemRetorno\":\"Operacao_Realizada\",\"idSync\":}");
        }
        else
        {

            //responde erro
            context.Response.Write("{\"StatusRetorno\":1,\"MensagemRetorno\":\"could not save file\"}");
        }

        body.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

gostaria de postar uma alternativa, no caso convertendo um Blob em base64.

```js
var uploadFile = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
var btBase64 = document.getElementById("btBase64");
var taBase64 = document.getElementById("taBase64");
var imgBase64 = document.getElementById("imgBase64");

btBase64.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (uploadFile.files.length > 0) {
    var file = uploadFile.files[0];
    
    blobToBase64(uploadFile.files[0], function (base64) {
      taBase64.innerHTML = base64;
      imgBase64.src = "data:" + file.type + ";base64," + base64;
    });    
    
    //if (file.type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
    //  imgBase64.src = URL.createObjectURL(uploadFile.files[0]);
    //}
  }
});

var blobToBase64 = function(blob, callback) {
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(e) { 
    var binary = [].slice.apply(new Uint8Array(fileReader.result));     
    var str = binary.map(function (charCode) {
      return String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    }).join("");  
    callback(btoa(str));
  };
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="uploadFile" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="btBase64" type="button" value="Para Base64" />
</div>
<div>
  <textarea id="taBase64" type="button" value="Para Base64" >
  </textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <img id="imgBase64" />
</div>
```

para pegar um arquivo local, você pode fazer uma requisição ajax:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', fileName, true);
xmlHttp.responseType = "blob";
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && (xmlHttp.status == 200 || xmlHttp.status == 0)) {        
    var base64 = blobToBase64(xmlHttp.response)
  }
}
xmlHttp.send();
```

Comment: Valeu, porem tenho uma dúvida, o retorno do arquivo convertido vem pela variável `base64`, caso o arquivo seja um uma imagem ou um vídeo e eu queira pegar o valor em `base64` e exibir em baixo do textarea(para testar se realmente esta funcionando corretamente a conversão) como devo fazer? eu tentei enviar assim `document.getElementById("imgBase64").innerHTML = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + base64 + '">';` porem não funcionou.

Comment: Vinicius, uma vez que você tenha um blob, você pode criar uma url para o blob, vou atualizar o exemplo.

Comment: Vinicius, atualizei o exemplo para montar a imagem no proprio source, porem deixei um trecho de codigo comentado, onde criamos uma URL para o arquivo em memoria (que é o que eu recomendo).

Comment: deu certo, porem com o meu código anterior eu enviava o arquivo em base64 para um ajax e ele enviava para o meu server side que decodificava e salvava o arquivo em um diretório, agora ele não esta conseguindo decodificar, ele envia o arquivo para meu diretório porem a imagem por exemplo abre toda preta, irei postar o código do meu server side caso consiga me ajuda. (Agradeço a atenção até o momento)

Comment: Vinicius, tinha um erro no `blobToBase64`, tenta denovo agora, vale lembrar que você tambem tem que passar o type do objeto serializado no AJAX.

Comment: esta funcionando agora, o server side esta decodificando, irei passar a imagem assim que o usuário tirar a foto, ele não poderá pegar da galeria, eu tenho como retorno da função que  tira foto o caminho+nome+extensão (file:/storage/../foto.jpg), tem como eu passar este retorno para a função de codificar e ela realizar a codificação?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27351/discussion-between-vinicius-vaz-and-tobymosque).

Comment: já tentou usar o [camera.getPicture](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture), ele inclusive já lhe retorna a imagem no formato que você precisa.

Comment: seria possível conversarmos pelo chat? Fica mais fácil para eu explicar a minha situação

Comment: firewall não permite.

Comment: Ok @TobyMosque, o que acontece é que o usuário pode enviar várias mídias (foto, áudio, vídeo) até o momento o meu app esta pegando estes arquivos e salvando todos os caminhos deles em uma div, que depois transformo em um vetor e mando para o meu ajax subir os dados, eu tenho uma função que funciona para imagens, o que precisava saber é se teria como eu adaptar a função que me mandou para receber o caminho da mídia transformar ela e enviar para o meu ajax. (O camera.getPicture não da por que não envio no momento que tiro a foto tenho que enviar depois, quando o usuário queira cadastrar)

Comment: @ViniciusVaz, neste caso você pode usar um [Storage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html), criar uma pequena tabela temporaria `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILES (file_uuid unique, name, type, base64)` para armazenar os arquivos, então quando o usuario precisa-se enviar teria apenas que ler o Storage e enviar por AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Para vídeo você pode usar:

```
    videodata = Base64.encodeToString(objByteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Para áudio você pode usar:

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-4.wav");
    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);                                       
    Utilities.log("~~~~~~~~ Encoded: ", encoded);

    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(encoded, 0);
    Utilities.log("~~~~~~~~ Decoded: ", Arrays.toString(decoded));

    try
    {
    File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-5.wav");
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file2, true);
    os.write(decoded);
    os.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Valeu, só fiquei com uma dúvida, quando eu vou converter uma imagem eu passo por parâmetro o caminho que ela esta, quais são os parâmetros que devo passar quando realizar a chamada destas funções?

Comment: Aparentemente a dúvida do AP é fazer essa conversão com Javascript, não Java.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tenho um codigo bem simples em python que eu desenvolvi, que pega um video .webm, converte pra base64 e salva no banco de dados mysql.
A primeira inclusão na tabela eu fiz a mão. depois o resto o programa faz(fiquei com preguiça de pensar).

```
import base64
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys
import string
import MySQLdb
from gi.repository import Gtk
import gtk
from time import time, sleep
from sched import scheduler
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog as filedialog

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="imagens")
cursor = db.cursor()


cursor.execute('SELECT codigo FROM CODIFICADAS ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1')
resultado = cursor.fetchall()
for dados in resultado:
    numero = dados[0]
    numerar = int(numero)
    if numerar >= 1:
        numerar = numerar +1
        numerar = int(numerar)


    nome = "arquivo %s" %(numerar)
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
imagem = filedialog.askopenfilename()
with open(imagem, "rb") as f:
           data = f.read()
           decode = data.encode("base64")
           decode = str(decode)
           gravar = open('ARQUIVO.txt' ,'w')
           gravar.write(decode)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO CODIFICADAS (nome, decode) VALUES( '" + nome + "',  '" + decode + "')")
db.commit()
```